# How to avoid sliding menu lag which causes stuttering in opening the fragment?

Tags: android, android-fragments, slidingmenu

In my application i have implemented the Sliding menu drawer in the main activity.
The design of the menu is customized and on click of listitem from the menu a fragment opens.

```
private class SlideMenuClickListener implements
        ListView.OnItemClickListener {
    @Override
    public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position,
                            long id) {
        // display view for selected nav drawer item
        displayView(position);
    }
}
private void displayView(int position) {
    // update the main content by replacing fragments
    Fragment fragment = null;
    switch (position) {
        case 0:
            fragment=new LastTransactionsDetails();

            break;
        case 1:
            fragment = new Statement_of_Transaction();
            break;
       case 2:
          fragment = new AccountDetails();

            break;
        case 3:
            fragment=new ProfileSetting();

            break;
           case 4:
            fragment=new LastTransactionsDetails();

            break;

        default:
            break;
    }

    if (fragment != null) {

        FragmentManager fragmentManager = getSupportFragmentManager();
        fragmentManager.beginTransaction().replace(R.id.frame_container, fragment).commit();
        // update selected item and title, then close the drawer
        mDrawerList.setItemChecked(position, true);
        mDrawerList.setSelection(position);
        setTitle(navMenuTitles[position]);
        mDrawerLayout.closeDrawer(mDrawerList);
    } else {
        // error in creating fragment
        Log.e("MainActivity", "Error in creating fragment");
    }
}
```

The closing of sliding menu shows a bit delay which causes stuttering of the menu. The fragment onCreateView is calling an async task containing calls to webservice methods. Is it because of the fragment loading that is causing the lag? If so then what change do i have make?
The fragment code is as follows :

```
@Override
public void onAttach(Context context) {
    super.onAttach(context);

    mActivity = context instanceof Activity ? (Activity) context : null;
    viewUtils = new ViewUtils(mActivity);
    webServicesParams = new WebServicesParams(mActivity);
    database = new DbAdapter(context);
    database.createDatabase();
    database.open();
    parseJsonResponse = new ParseJsonResponse();
    showProgressDialog();

}
@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {

    View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.last_transactions_details, container, false);

    listView_transactions = (ListView) rootView.findViewById(R.id.listView_transactions);

    try {


        String jsonResponse = webServicesParams.Last_Transaction();
        arr_last_trans = parseJsonResponse.getTierDetails(jsonResponse);

        adapter = new LastTransactionAdapter(arr_last_trans,getActivity());
        listView_transactions .setAdapter(adapter);

        dismissProgressDialog();
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add some delay after navigation item click and before loading fragment, to smoothly close the slidemenu.

```
private final Handler mDrawerHandler = new Handler();
//Wait for few millis before replacing fragment to allow slidemenu to fully close. 
public void smoothReplaceFragment(final Fragment fragment) {
    mDrawerHandler.removeCallbacksAndMessages(null);
    mDrawerHandler.postDelayed(new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
             replaceFragment(fragment);
        }
    }, 350);
}

//Replace Fragment
public void replaceFragment(Fragment fragment) {
    FragmentManager fragmentManager = getSupportFragmentManager();
    fragmentManager.beginTransaction().replace(R.id.frame_container, fragment).commit();
}
```